# how can we find the outliers through clustering approach if the data has just one class?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, outliers

I want to find the outliers in the data through clustering. I mean after clustering, the samples that are the most distant ones be considered as outliers. I figure out that my data has just one class, so in this way can clustering help to find the outliers or Is there any other way to find the outliers when the data has just one class?

Comment: It would be useful to provide some more info about how your dataset looks like. Number of variables, type of variables, etc.

Comment: You might look at DBSCAN.  It explicitly classifies some points as "noise",  i.e. not in any cluster.

Comment: As there is no rigorous definition of outliers in general, I fear you will not get any really useful answers. So you can try to provide a clear definition of outliers or share more of your problem (dimensionality of the data, type of data, problem, etc) to get more fruitful answers.

Comment: @َAntoniosk:my data has 44 variables of both categorical and continuous ones.The variables are in the types of numeric,factor,date,nominal,....

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a dedicated outlier detection method like LOF (Local Outlier Factor) that does not need clustering or classes?

ELKI (probably the standard tool for outlier detection) has way over a dozen outlier detection methods. including some clustering based methods (as the one you suggested), although I don't think these work as good as the dedicated methods.

Comment: Upvote for LOF! There's R package for that and their original paper is really nice

Comment: IIRC the R package is rather slow though, and sometimes other - simpler - methods such as kNN outlier detection work even better. I also like LoOP because it gives this "probability" in 0 to 1.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: My data has both categorical and continuous variables so I can't use LOF because LOF can just work on NUMERIC data.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: As I said before Since my data has both categorical and continuous variables , can dissimilarity matrix of the data be used instead of my data in order to use LOF for outlier detection?

Comment: LOF works with non-numeric data. Just choose a distance such as Gower's.

Comment: The quality of the result will, however, depend *very much* on the quality of your dissimilarity measure.